# How to insert multiple items using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to insert multiply items using foreach loop in php and mysql. When i insert its insert null values. any ideas as to what i should fix?

```
  $itemNo = $statement->fetchColumn();

        $item_name =  ($_POST["item_name"]);

        $item_price =  ($_POST["item_price"]);

        $item_quantity = ($_POST["item_quantity"]);

        $item_total =  ($_POST["item_total"]);

    $statement = $connect->prepare("
      INSERT INTO product 
      ( `item_no`,`item_name`, `item_price`, `item_quantity`, `item_total`)
      VALUES ('$itemNo','$item_name','$item_price','$item_quantity','$item_total')
    ");

    foreach($_POST["item_name"] as $subscription){
    $statement->execute(
      array(
        ':itemNo'                   =>  $itemNo,
        ':item_name '               =>  trim($_POST["item_name"]),
        ':item_price'               =>  trim($_POST["item_price"]),
        ':item_quantity'            =>  trim($_POST["item_quantity"]),
        ':item_total'               =>  trim($_POST["item_total"])
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are these arrays or strings? You're treating them as though they're both, or randomly switch.

Comment: this is totally wrong `VALUES ('$itemNo','$item_name','$item_price','$item_quantity','$item_total')`

Answer (score 3):

You need to put placeholders in the query, not variables, to match the parameters in the call to `execute()`.

```
$statement = $connect->prepare("
  INSERT INTO product 
  ( `item_no`,`item_name`, `item_price`, `item_quantity`, `item_total`)
  VALUES (:itemNo,:item_name,:item_price,:item_quantity,:item_total)
");
```

And if `$_POST['item_name']` is an array, you can't use `trim($_POST['item_name'])` as a value. The argument to `trim()` has to be a string, not an array. If these post variables are all arrays, you need to index them.

```
foreach ($item_name as $index => $subscription) {
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':itemNo'                   =>  $itemNo,
            ':item_name '               =>  trim($subscription),
            ':item_price'               =>  trim($item_price[$index]),
            ':item_quantity'            =>  trim($item_quantity[$index]),
            ':item_total'               =>  trim($item_total[$index])
        )
    );
}
```